# Show that $\mathfrak c +{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ using "presenters"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that $\mathfrak c +{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$ using "presenters".

For example, in order to prove that $\mathfrak c +\mathfrak c=\mathfrak c$
We can show that:

$$\mathfrak c =\left| \left( 0,2 \right) \right|=\left| \left( 0,1 \right) \right|+\left| \left[ 1,2 \right) \right|=\mathfrak c +\mathfrak c$$

I thought about picking: $\mathbb{N} + (0,1)$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Clarification**
"presenter": A set with the desired cardinal. It's not a well-known term I guess but we use it in our course.

Comment: Instead of $\aleph$, which is horribly ambiguous, the standard notation is $\mathfrak c$ -- Or one can always use $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: What is a "presenter"?

Comment: Take $\mathbb N \cup [-1,0]$ or something. @AndresCaicedo Probably an "example"

Comment: Hmm.. it's a set with the desired cardinal.

Comment: @AlexR, Actually I thought about it, but got stuck there.

Comment: @AnnieOK To avoid confusion, you may want to add that definition to the question. (Not everybody reads the comments.)

Comment: @AnnieOK Thank you for the edit.

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out. Should I answer my own question?

Comment: The term is representative. (And yes, you should answer your own question. But I think it's a duplicate anyway.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed. Can you give me an hint please?

Comment: @Annie: About the use of $\aleph$ as the cardinality of the continuum, it is an accepted (even if less common nowadays) use. Cantor used it as well. I do agree that $\frak c$ has a better chance that people don't confuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you should find two sets, $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|=\aleph$ and $|B|=\aleph_0$, and these sets are disjoint, and a bijection between $A\cup B$ and $A$.

You already know that $[0,1]$ has cardinality $\aleph$, consider $B=\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$. So let's use these sets, and let me give you some hint.

**HINT:** Recall the proof that $\Bbb Z$ is countable. Fix some countable subset of $[0,1]$ (e.g. $\frac1n$) and modify the aforementioned proof to show that $A\cup B\sim A$.

Comment: I think it's a well defined bijection. right?

$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   1/x,x\in \mathbb{N}\backslash \{0,1\}  \\
   (x+2)/3,x\in (0,1)  \\
\end{matrix} \right.$

Comment: Well, it's definitely injective from $(0,1)\cup\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Oh, but onto $(0,1)$. silly me

Comment: Alternatively, I can find an injective function from the other side which is easy. And we're done :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1)$?

Comment: Hmm.. Yes. I have it in my notes.

Comment: Annie, reducing this to a Cantor-Bernstein is the same as saying $\mathfrak c\leq\mathfrak c+\aleph_0\leq\mathfrak c$. I agree it's not 100% clear whether or not you can utilize Cantor-Bernstein here, or do you have to find an explicit bijection. You should ask your instructors for clarification on that. But given the fact that finding a bijection is not very difficult either, I've given you a hint to do that.

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at my notes. I believe it's relatively easy from this point. Thanks.