# $|A|=\mathcal c \ \ |B|=\aleph_0 \ \ A\cap B=\emptyset$ prove that $ |A\cup B|=\mathcal c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Let $|A|=\mathcal c, \ |B|=\aleph_0, \ A\cap B=\emptyset,$ Prove that $ |A\cup B|=\mathcal c$

So $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ but this just leads to cardinal arithmetic which I don't think is the right approach.

Maybe embedding could work ? There has to be a 1-1 function from $A$ to $(0,1)$ and from $B$ to the naturals, so $A\cup B = \{x\in [0,1], y | x\in \mathbb R, y\in \mathbb N\}$ and now it's enough to know that for all $x$ the cardinality of this set is $\mathcal c$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763262/show-that-mathfrak-c-aleph-0-mathfrak-c-using-presenters

Comment: @Martin:I knew it looked familiar, and I tried to search for a duplicate. But I couldn't find one. Which is strange, since I was the one answering that question, and I usually remember these things.

Comment: @Asaf I've simply googled for ["\aleph_0 \mathfrak c" site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22\aleph_0+\mathfrak%20c%22+site:math.stackexchange.com). They might be other questions here asking about the same thing. (BTW the other question is IMO not a duplicate, since it restricts solutions to a specific method.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cardinal arithmetic **is** finding injections. The fact that you write something like:$$\mathfrak c+\aleph_0=\mathfrak c$$ can only be used after you have proved that there is a bijection between two sets, one of cardinality continuum, and another which can be partitioned into sets of sizes continuum and $\aleph_0$.

Of course if you haven't proved these things yet, then you should. But if you have proved some basic things about cardinal arithmetic, then this is a far easier approach: $$\mathfrak c\leq\mathfrak c+\aleph_0\leq\frak c+c=c$$ (Where the latter equality is witnessed by the fact that $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$).

Answer (score 3):

Your embedding shows (as $A\cup B \subseteq \mathbb R$) in this case, $|A\cup B| \le \mathfrak c$. As $\mathfrak c \le |A\cup B|$ (since $A \subseteq A \cup B$), the statement follows by Schröder-Bernstein.